# What are some troubleshooting techniques for vim/ALE issues

Tags: javascript, vim, eslint

I'm using vim with `w0rp/ale` (aka `dense-analysis/ale`) and have been for several years. It suddenly stopped working and I can't figure out why. It will neither lint nor fix.

`ALEInfo` shows what appear to be normal values, but there are no commands in the Command History.

If I run the command `eslint -f unix --stdin --stdin-filename src/App.js < src/App.js` I get back the expected eslint errors (two of them).

(Updated) NOTE, however, that `ALECodeAction` returns `No active LSPs`

I've tried removing my `.eslintrc.json` in case it has errors (no luck) and tried simplifying / trying new combinations of `g:ale_linters` in case that was the issue, but no love there either.

Any suggestions for some trouble-shooting approaches?

Here's the various configurations I've tried in my .vimrc:

```
let g:ale_linters_explicit = 1
let g:ale_linter_aliases = {'jsx': ['css', 'javascript']}
let g:ale_sign_column_always = 1
" extended logging
let g:ale_history_log_output = 1
let g:ale_history_enabled = 1

" new fixers & linters 2021-01-15
" let g:ale_fixers = {'javascript': ['xo'], "json": ['prettier']}
" let g:ale_linters = {'javascript': ['xo', 'prettier', 'eslint']}

" ole fixers & linters working until prettier install/Grant
let g:ale_fixers = {
\   '*': ['remove_trailing_lines', 'trim_whitespace'],
\   'javascript': ['eslint'],
\}

" " Only run linters named in ale_linters settings.
let g:ale_linters = {
\   'javascript': ['stylelint', 'eslint'],
\   'jsx': ['stylelint', 'eslint'],
\   'javascript.jsx': ['stylelint', 'eslint'],
\   'bash': ['sh'],
\}
```

Here's the `ALEInfo` (updated):

```
 Current Filetype: javascript.jsx
Available Linters: ['eslint', 'fecs', 'flow', 'flow-language-server', 'jscs', 'jshint', 'standard', 'tsserver', 'xo', 'csslint', 'fecs', 'stylelint', 'eslint', 'fecs', 'flow', 'flow-language-server', 'jscs', 'jshint', 'standard', 'tsserver', 'xo']
  Enabled Linters: ['stylelint', 'eslint']
  Ignored Linters: []
 Suggested Fixers: 
  'eslint' - Apply eslint --fix to a file.
  'fecs' - Apply fecs format to a file.
  'importjs' - automatic imports for javascript
  'prettier' - Apply prettier to a file.
  'prettier_eslint', 'prettier-eslint' - Apply prettier-eslint to a file.
  'prettier_standard', 'prettier-standard' - Apply prettier-standard to a file.
  'remove_trailing_lines' - Remove all blank lines at the end of a file.
  'standard' - Fix JavaScript files using standard --fix
  'trim_whitespace' - Remove all trailing whitespace characters at the end of every line.
  'xo' - Fix JavaScript/TypeScript files using xo --fix.
 Linter Variables:

 Global Variables:

let g:ale_cache_executable_check_failures = v:null
let g:ale_change_sign_column_color = v:null
let g:ale_command_wrapper = v:null
let g:ale_completion_delay = v:null
let g:ale_completion_enabled = 0
let g:ale_completion_max_suggestions = v:null
let g:ale_disable_lsp = 0
let g:ale_echo_cursor = 1
let g:ale_echo_msg_error_str = 'Error'
let g:ale_echo_msg_format = v:null
let g:ale_echo_msg_info_str = 'Info'
let g:ale_echo_msg_warning_str = 'Warning'
let g:ale_enabled = 1
let g:ale_fix_on_save = 0
let g:ale_fixers = {'*': ['remove_trailing_lines', 'trim_whitespace'], 'javascript': ['eslint']}
let g:ale_history_enabled = 1
let g:ale_history_log_output = 1
let g:ale_keep_list_window_open = v:null
let g:ale_lint_delay = 200
let g:ale_lint_on_enter = 1
let g:ale_lint_on_filetype_changed = 1
let g:ale_lint_on_insert_leave = 1
let g:ale_lint_on_save = 1
let g:ale_lint_on_text_changed = 'normal'
let g:ale_linter_aliases = {'jsx': ['css', 'javascript']}
let g:ale_linters = {'jsx': ['stylelint', 'eslint'], 'javascript.jsx': ['stylelint', 'eslint'], 'bash': ['sh'], 'javascript': ['stylelint', 'eslint']}
let g:ale_linters_explicit = 1
let g:ale_linters_ignore = {}
let g:ale_list_vertical = v:null
let g:ale_list_window_size = v:null
let g:ale_loclist_msg_format = v:null
let g:ale_lsp_root = {}
let g:ale_max_buffer_history_size = 20
let g:ale_max_signs = v:null
let g:ale_maximum_file_size = v:null
let g:ale_open_list = v:null
let g:ale_pattern_options = v:null
let g:ale_pattern_options_enabled = v:null
let g:ale_set_balloons = 0
let g:ale_set_highlights = 1
let g:ale_set_loclist = 1
let g:ale_set_quickfix = 0
let g:ale_set_signs = 1
let g:ale_sign_column_always = 1
let g:ale_sign_error = v:null
let g:ale_sign_info = v:null
let g:ale_sign_offset = v:null
let g:ale_sign_style_error = v:null
let g:ale_sign_style_warning = v:null
let g:ale_sign_warning = v:null
let g:ale_sign_highlight_linenrs = v:null
let g:ale_statusline_format = v:null
let g:ale_type_map = v:null
let g:ale_use_global_executables = v:null
let g:ale_virtualtext_cursor = 0
let g:ale_warn_about_trailing_blank_lines = 1
let g:ale_warn_about_trailing_whitespace = 1
  Command History:
```

Comment: Please show the result of `:ALEInfo` for file in which you are trying to use ale, currently you are showing `ALEInfo` for your vimrc file. When you say ale is not working, do you mean fixing or linting? Please make sure that you have installed eslint in your project before using it.

Comment: Sorry; pasted the wrong copy of ALEInfo; now updated. As you can see from the `ALEInfo` output, no linting commands are executed. And yes, `eslint` is installed as you can see from the output when running from the command line; also works as `npx eslint ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG: I don't know what happened, but it's working again! Maybe once before I've had this kind of issue with ALE, so I tried a number of things over a period of serval hours (ALE is fundamental to my work flow) none of which seemed to help:

1. Reinstall ALE
2. Reinstall stylelint, eslint including `npx eslint --init` to start clean
3. Try prettier
4. Making many changes to the configuration/settings, including
   stripping all but the most fundamental pugins.
5. Try different filetype settings
6. aliasing/not aliasing eslint
7. git bisect around recent changes
8. rebooting my machine

And t*esting after each change.

I finally hit on a solution: sad to say I don't know **why** this was a problem in the first place nor **why** this fixed it, but here it is.

This morning, I tried installing an LSP, just for grins: `typescript-language-server`. This didn't help, but when I uninstalled it and tried ALEInfo again, now it's working!